# Distribute 20 people into two queues with at least two

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Twenty people are queuing. Two new lines are opened and 8 people rush there. At least two of these 8 end up in each queue. In how many ways can these queues be created?

If everyone was in one queue there would be $ \binom{20}{12}$ ways.

I need to figure out in how many ways I can distribute 8 people in two queues, restricted to at least two in each queue.
Then multiply that with $ \binom{20}{12}$. Is that correct? How do I figure out the second part?

Comment: Do you want to mean there should be at least eight people in the second queue and there cannot be less that two people in the first queue ?

Comment: Typically, in a queue, order matters. So I would guess that that's the case here too.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify. A total of 8 people leave the queue, and these are the ones that should be distributed in the two queues.

Comment: I think $C(20,12).P(12,12).C(8,2)P(2,2)C(6,6)P(6,6)+C(20,12).P(12,12).C(8,3)P(3,3)C(5,5)P(5,5)+.....+C(20,12).P(12,12).C(8,6)P(6,6)C(2,2)P(2,2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$20$ people are standing in a line. $8$ leave to form two new queues. The new queues can have $(2,6)$ or $(3,5)$ or $(4,4)$ or $(5,3)$ or $(6,2)$ people respectively.

You're correct in saying the result is $\binom{20}{8}$ times *something*.

For second part, there are $5$ cases of arranging $8$ people. The *something* is $5\cdot 8!$

Slightly shorter route, we have $5$ ways of arranging $8$ people from $20$. That's $$ ^{20}P _{8} \times 5$$